# How to upload and read XML file in servlet along with their tags

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

Please advise me to read the XML file along with their tags. I am able to retrieve the contain of the tags but not the tag name.

Code snippet:

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

try {

    List<FileItem> fields = upload.parseRequest(request);
    out.println("Number of fields: " + fields.size() + "<br/><br/>");
    Iterator<FileItem> it = fields.iterator();
    if (!it.hasNext()) {
        out.println("No fields found");
        return;
    }
    out.println("<table border=\"1\">");
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        out.println("<tr>");
        FileItem fileItem = it.next();
        boolean isFormField = fileItem.isFormField();
        if (isFormField) {
            out.println("<td>regular form field</td><td>FIELD NAME: " + fileItem.getFieldName() + "<br/>STRING: " + fileItem.getString());
            out.println("</td>");
        } else {
            out.println("<td>file form field</td><td>FIELD NAME: " + fileItem.getFieldName() +
            "<br/>STRING: " + fileItem.getString() +
            "<br/>NAME: " + fileItem.getName() +
            "<br/>CONTENT TYPE: " + fileItem.getContentType() +
            "<br/>SIZE (BYTES): " + fileItem.getSize() +
            "<br/>TO STRING: " + fileItem.toString() 
            );

            out.println("</td>");
        }
```

XML used :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 -<students>
-<student>
 <name>John</name>
 <grade>B</grade>
 <age>12</age>
 </student>
 -<student>
 <name>Mary</name>
 <grade>A</grade>
 <age>11</age>
 </student>
 -<student>
 <name>Simon</name>
 <grade>A</grade>
 <age>18</age>
 </student>
 </students>
```

Output :

```
 FIELD NAME: Browse
 STRING: - John B 12 Mary A 11 Simon A 18 
 NAME: Samplexml.xml
 CONTENT TYPE: text/xml
 SIZE (BYTES): 313
 TO STRING: name=Samplexml.xml,StoreLocation=C:\Users\Bramesh\AppData\Local\Temp\upload_1aa898c7_7c38_4e32_958b_25efcf0b37c8_00000000.tmp, size=313 bytes, isFormField=false, FieldName=Browse
```

Comment: Yet another question begging "here, do this homework for me"

Answer (score 0):

If you have an xml schema the easiest way to do this is with JAXB, which with a little work will unmarshall a stream to a bunch of objects that represent your xml.  If you do not have a schema then this can be accomplished with a sax parser.  For a tutorial on how to read xml using a sax parser see http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/.
Using you example above you would call getInputStream() and then pass that to your SAXParser with the handler being used to extract out the information of the elements and their values.